# getting multiple checkbox values in ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code here in my ajax:

```
var userCheckbox = $("input[name=chk]:checked").val();
```

and this is the checkbox in my html:

```
<input id="checkbx" type="checkbox" name="chk" value="apple"/>apple</td>
<input id="checkbx" type="checkbox" name="chk" value="corn"/>corn</td>
<input id="checkbx" type="checkbox" name="chk" value="tomato"/>tomato</td>
<input id="checkbx" type="checkbox" name="chk" value="juice"/>juice</td>
```

but I'm only getting one value. how can I get multiple values? someone said to me that I should use a loop statement but I don't know where to put it.

can anyone please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.map()` to create an array of the values:

```
var userCheckbox = $("input[name=chk]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Also, your ID's are repeating, remember, ID's **must** be unique.

Comment: I'm getting "Array" text when displayed.

Comment: Well, its an array of values.

Comment: I mean I'm not getting the values of the checkboxes.

Comment: Try logging `userCheckbox[0]` -- is there a value there?